# looping over rows with difftime

Tags: r, loops, row, difftime

I have a column of times under `timefact`

```
> head(foo)
  cnrd_marsh            timefact timefact_hour
1         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:34:00            14
2         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:15:00            14
3         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:10:00            14
4         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:58:00            13
5         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:57:00            13
6         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:39:00            13
```

My objective is to create a fourth column containing integer values that represent the number of minutes difference (difftime) between the given row and the row above it.  In addition, I need to exclude all cases where the `timefact_hour`is different from the row above  In other words, I only need to find the differences of rows that share the same `hour`.

I was able to write the following code, which works in that it takes the difference from one row to the next, but it does not convert posix times to character and it does not skip over instances where `hour` is different.

```
output1 <- data.frame("timefact" = character(), diff_time = numeric(0)) 

for (i in 2:nrow(foo)){

  diff_time <- difftime(foo[i, "timefact"], foo[i-1, "timefact"], tz = "EST", units = "mins")
  new_row <- c(foo[i, "timefact"], diff_time)
  output1[nrow(output1) + 1,] = new_row

}

> head(output1)
  timefact diff_time
1     <NA>       -19
2     <NA>        -5
3     <NA>       -12
4     <NA>        -1
5     <NA>       -18
6     <NA>       -31
```

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(foo)
structure(list(cnrd_marsh = structure(c(91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L), .Label = c("", "1", "10", "11", "11К", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1К", "2", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "33К", "34", "34К", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"4", "40", "41", "42", "43", "43К", "44", "45", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"6", "60", "61", "62", "63", "63К", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"7", "70", "70К", "71", "72", "73", "74", "76", "77", "78", 
"79", "8", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "88", "9", 
"БК", "БЧ"), class = "factor"), timefact = structure(c(1460057640, 
1460056500, 1460056200, 1460055480, 1460055420, 1460054340, 1460052480, 
1460052360, 1460051340, 1460051040, 1460050440, 1460050380, 1460049360, 
1460048160, 1460048040, 1460046960, 1460046720, 1460046300, 1460045340, 
1460045160, 1460043540, 1460042880, 1460042520, 1460041920, 1460041140, 
1460040120, 1460039760, 1460038860, 1460038620, 1460038080, 1460038020, 
1460037240, 1460036280, 1460035800, 1460034960, 1460034780, 1460034120, 
1460034060, 1460033340, 1460032500, 1460032140, 1460031300, 1460031000, 
1460030340, 1460030340, 1460029800, 1460029200, 1460028300, 1460025720, 
1460090700, 1460088660, 1460088600, 1460087760, 1460087580, 1460086980, 
1460086980, 1460086320, 1460085300, 1460085180, 1460084340, 1460084160, 
1460083620, 1460083620, 1460082780, 1460081820, 1460081760, 1460080740, 
1460080500, 1460080200, 1460079360, 1460079180, 1460077260, 1460076840, 
1460076600, 1460076360, 1460075820, 1460074740, 1460070660, 1460070480, 
1460069100, 1460068800, 1460068140, 1460068140, 1460067060, 1460063880, 
1460063460, 1460062380, 1460062080, 1460061360, 1460061300, 1460059920, 
1460057880, 1460057640, 1460060760, 1460060580, 1460059080, 1460058780, 
1460058240, 1460058180, 1460057220), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "EST"), timefact_hour = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L
)), .Names = c("cnrd_marsh", "timefact", "timefact_hour"), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to ask how to modify the code to get the proper output. Here is an example of what the output should look like

```
   > head(output)
  cnrd_marsh            timefact timefact_hour timefact_diff
1         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:34:00            14            NA
2         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:15:00            14            19
3         БЧ 2016-04-07 14:10:00            14             5
4         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:58:00            13            NA
5         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:57:00            13             1
6         БЧ 2016-04-07 13:39:00            13            18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
library(dplyr)

#a is your data.frame

#Create leads of your timefact  & timefact_hour column
# Use ifelse to assign a value to difftime depending on if leading timefact and current timefact is equal or not

b= lead(a$timefact)

a$DiffTimes = c(NA, ifelse(a$timefact_hour[-nrow(a)] == lead(a$timefact_hour)[-nrow(a)], difftime(a$timefact[-nrow(a)], b[-nrow(a)], units = "mins",tz="EST"),NA))

> head(a)
     cnrd_marsh       timefact              timefact_hour DiffTimes
 1 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 14:34:00            14        NA
 2 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 14:15:00            14        19
 3 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 14:10:00            14         5
 4 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 13:58:00            13        NA
 5 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 13:57:00            13         1
 6 <U+0411><U+0427> 2016-04-07 13:39:00            13        18
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably using `data.table` like this.

EDIT: Since the mix up of `timefact_hour`, the usual grouping would produce unexpected results. So, we can add `i` filter beforehand to check if `timefact_hour` changes. The first `[` is to create lag variable for `timefact` to assist the `diff_time` calculation. It can be removed afterwards if desired.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(foo)
foo[, lag.timefact := shift(timefact)][which(timefact_hour-lag(timefact_hour)== 0), diff_time := difftime(lag.timefact, timefact, tz = "EST", units = "mins")]
```

Comment: I have tried this code before, but it produces many undesirable negative values: if you apply it on the sample data you will see negative values at in the last 25 rows.  I have no idea how they occur

Comment: hm, its because the timefact_hour is mixed, changing back and forth between 14 and 15, while `data.table` will group them without caring about the mix-up (the 14 group actually even starts at the beginning of the data).

Comment: That makes sense. Actually, I would like to avoid grouping by the `timefact_ hour` variable altogether, because the list of times is in an order that I would not like to alter.  How would one go about taking the differences (only between same hour rows)  without grouping by time_fact hour?